# Making Music Playlist

Tags: html, audio, text

I'm trying to make a music website to display my music. I figured out to how to somewhat make a creative player by putting my songs in a  box. However, I don't know how to add text to my boxes. Whenever I add text to the  it expands the  box, making it uneven. Does anyone have any tips on how to add text without making the box uneven?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
</style>
<body>

<div>
<audio controls>
  <source src="Too High.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Too High.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>

<div>
<audio controls>
  <source src="Visions of the mind.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Visions of the mind.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>

<div>
<audio controls>
  <source src="Let me know.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Let me know.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height` to set all the divs to a similar minimum height

```css
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 290px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
  
  min-height:110px; /*CHANGE THIS NUMBER */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="Too High.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="Too High.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
  <p>Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text </p>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="Visions of the mind.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="Visions of the mind.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text Here is some text </p>
  <audio controls>
    <source src="Let me know.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="Let me know.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm trying to add the track title above the audio player. Whenever I add text it makes the box bigger.

Comment: How much text are you adding? I edited the above example to show you what must be moved for the text to be above the controls. *(Compare the original #1 with the modified #2 and #3)* The box will get bigger if you add more text than there is room for at the initial size of `110px`. If you add more text, make that number bigger to keep all the boxes approximately the same size.

Comment: Where would I add text?

Comment: The issue I'm having is I want everything to look clean and line everything up to look like a playlist. I want the divs to be smaller but have the song title and some information, if that makes sense. The way I have it now is the divs are big and take up too much space.